# Handling Errors with db.Database.SqlQuery

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I came across an issue today where I had a query that was failing. I am using `db.Database.SqlQuery<T>()` to query another applications data. We have a custom view over their data. Today the admin rebuilt the indexes in the software and in the process deleted the custom view. While that is an issue that SO can't solve, the issue you can help with is gracefully handling the case where the view no longer exists.

For the main application, we are using this data as supplemental data. Meaning that it isn't critical to have the information display if the server or table can't be reached. The query is run in the follow WebApi action (I added a few comments based on my observations while debugging.):

```
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetByAddress(string id)
    {
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> response;

        string sql = // my sql statement;
        List<object> parameterList = new List<object>();
        parameterList.Add(id.ToUpper());
        object[] param = parameterList.ToArray();

        // This is worthless since the following line will completely replace this
        IEnumerable<CallsForService> calls = new List<CallsForService>(); 
        // If the table does not exist, this does not throw an error, instead it creates a different object with the error details.
        calls = db.Database.SqlQuery<CallsForService>(sql, param);

        response = Task.FromResult<HttpResponseMessage>(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, calls));
        return response;
    }
```

My question then is how do I check for these errors and at least gracefully send back to the calling application an empty list. I can then log these errors with ELMAH so I can catch the issue and get it fixed.

Comment: Can you wrap this in an try ... catch ... block, and in catch block to return your empty result.

Answer (score 0):

The query is not executed until the results are enumerated, so you can just count the number of records returned and make it raise an error if there any.

```
calls = db.Database.SqlQuery<CallsForService>(sql, param);
var recCount = calls.Count();
```

Any errors raised after the last line will be caught by the try/catch block.